# Methods to prepare lactic acid from acetaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I got one method [here](using acetaldehyde and carbon monoxide)[1](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/i360033a018).

But is there any alternative method (using specific catalyst)?

Comment: What is the downvote for?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter *or* the upvoter, but it would be really nice if you add a summary of what's written there here. I could assume the downvote is because someone wasn't inclined to click on an external link to find out what your question really is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fairly simple two step synthesis involves nucleophilic addition of $\ce{HCN}$ to the carbonyl group and then aqueous hydrolysis of the nitrile to yield the carboxylic acid product.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Acetylene + $\ce{HCN-Ba(CN)2}$ → vinyl cyanide

Vinyl cyanide - hydrolysis → acetaldehyde cyanohydrin

Acetaldehyde cyanohydrin - dil HCl → lactic acid